# xdotool send request in Postman

Tags: command-line, xdotool

I am trying to "Send Request" in Postman active tab from terminal with `xdotool`.

In Postman, we can use `ctrl+enter` key combination to "Send Request". So I tried:

`xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Postman key ctrl+Return`

This command doesn't raise any errors, but nothing happened with Postman. So could you tell me what is the right command to "Send Request" in current active Postman tab?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I have run `xwininfo` command to ensure the class is Postman. This is the result of `xwininfo` command:

```
xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.


xwininfo: Window id: 0x420000d "Postman"

  Absolute upper-left X:  1
  Absolute upper-left Y:  52
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 681
  Height: 715
  Depth: 24
  Visual: 0x21
  Visual Class: TrueColor
  Border width: 0
  Class: InputOutput
  Colormap: 0x20 (installed)
  Bit Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Window Gravity State: NorthWestGravity
  Backing Store State: NotUseful
  Save Under State: no
  Map State: IsViewable
  Override Redirect State: no
  Corners:  +1+52  -684+52  -684-1  +1-1
  -geometry 681x715+-10--10
```

Output of `xprop|grep 'CLASS\|NAME'` command:

```
WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Postman"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Postman"
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "postman", "Postman"
WM_LOCALE_NAME(STRING) = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Try introducing a short delay before the key press, e.g.  insert `sleep 0.3` before `key`

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for your replying. From your idea, I have tried: 
`xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Postman sleep 0.3 key ctrl+Return`, I changed 0.3 to 1 also, but it is still nothing happened in Postman.

Comment: I am not familiar with Postman, so I cannot help there nor test.

Comment: Instead of being specific, try to write a less "picky" command, for example, `xdotool search Postman key ctrl+Return`. If it works, you can then try to narrow its scope adding the other options. Did you make sure the class is `Postman` with `xwininfo` or `xprop`? Update your question with that information.

Comment: @vanadium anw, thank you for support.

Comment: @Quasímodo I edited my question. I tried `xdotool search Postman key ctrl+Return` command, too. But it's not work.

Comment: Sorry, `xwininfo` does not show window class, `xprop` does. We're interested in lines WM_NAME and WM_CLASS, so please add `xprop|grep 'CLASS\|NAME'` output.

Comment: @Quasímodo I added output of `xprop` command :D

Comment: It should be working... After my attempts to do it also failed, I found this <https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215543/388654> which may be related to the problem.